# How to flatten chained dependent http request with pipe and map

Tags: angular, rxjs

I was able to chain three http requests for which every subsequent request depends on the result of the previous one. How can I **flatten** the nested pipes and maps in the following example?

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-chain-http-request',
  templateUrl: './chain-http-request.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chain-http-request.component.css']
})
export class ChainHttpRequestComponent implements OnInit {
  character: any;
  homeworld: any;
  mostPopularMovie: any;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.http
    .get('https://swapi.co/api/people/1')
    .pipe(map((character: any) => {
      this.character = character;
      this.http
        .get(character.homeworld)
        .pipe(map((homeworld: any) => {
          this.homeworld = homeworld;
          this.http
            .get(homeworld.films[0])
            .pipe(map((mostPopularMovie: any) => {
              this.mostPopularMovie = mostPopularMovie;
              }))
            .subscribe(() => {
              console.log('mostPopularMovie loaded');
            });
          }))
        .subscribe(() => {
          console.log('homeworld loaded');
        });
      }))
    .subscribe(() => {
      console.log('people loaded');
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you meant to simplify your statement,
this should do the trick.

```
this.http
.get('https://swapi.co/api/people/1')
.pipe(
   tap(character => console.log(character)),
   switchMap((character: any) => this.http.get(character.homeworld)),
   tap(homeworld => console.log(homeworld)),   
   switchMap((homeworld: any) => this.http.get(homeworld.films[0])),
   tap(mostPopularMovie => console.log(mostPopularMovie))
).subscribe();
```

Comment: Just a tip, you can shorten the `tap` ops to `tap(console.log)`.

Comment: is this what you were looking for @philipp-fx?

Comment: Thanks, @jcal exactly what I was looking for!! :-)